# How to get the correct value from SerialPort.BytesToRead?

Tags: c#, serial-port

Sometimes the value of SerialPort.BytesToRead is 0 at the time that I test to see if it contains data, but when my application hits a breakpoint a few lines later, I can see that it has a number of bytes.

For example:

I write some data to the serial port. I then call a method to read the response:

```
var bytes = new List<byte>();
var byteCount = _serialPortWrapper.BytesToRead; // the value 0 is stored in byteCount

while (_serialPortWrapper.BytesToRead > 0) // this is 0, so it doesn't go in here
{
    try
    {
        bytes.Add(_serialPortWrapper.ReadByte());
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

MyPacket packet; // I set a breakpoint here and I can see that data is available
if (MyPacket.TryParse(bytes.ToArray(), out packet))
{
    return packet;
}

return null;
```

When I set the breakpoint at `ProprietaryPacket packet;` I can see data is available. In fact, at that point if I drag the cursor up to `bytes.Add(_serialPortWrapper.ReadByte());` and let it run again, all the data I expect gets populated into `bytes` and `ProprietaryPacket.TryParse` will then work.

How can I make this work so that `BytesToRead` will return the correct value the first time and then the `ReadByte()` method will work?

**edit** Note, if I add `Thread.Sleep(500);` before any of the above runs, it works every time. I don't want to do this though, because it's a bit of a hack. Is there any way around this?

Comment: 0 is the correct value at the point it was read. what's calling this code, you aren't polling are you?

Comment: If you don't want to use the DataReceived event then just call ReadByte() directly.  It will block until a byte is available.

Comment: Tony is wondering what the code that is calling this is doing. Polling in this context means repeatedly checking if there are bytes to read. This is generally considered an inefficient way of doing things. In contrast to polling there is the event-driven model where the OS or framework notifies you when there is data to read so you don't waste time constantly checking.

Comment: Polling is check to see if there's any data to read. Event based as in DataReceived is read when there is some. Why are you expecting some different number of bytes than there is, it shouldn't matter, in fact it mustn't matter for a robust design

Answer (score 0):

Instead of watching for the `BytesToRead` you should subscribe to the [`DataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event. Then you will automatically be called when new data arrives.

If you don't know how to do this on the above link to the corresponding MSDN page you'll find a example on how to subscribe to the event and what you should do within it.

Comment: I was using `DataRecieved` but it was giving me inconsistent results compared to what I saw in the port sniffer that I am using. I'm trying to use BytesToRead to have more direct control over what I'm gettin back.

Comment: You can't compare what you see in the port sniffer with what you see in the code, unless you choke the input, in which case you wouldn't need to look. How many bytes there are to be read, is how many there are. It's your expectation that is the problem, not the code.

Answer (score 0):

The value is correct at the time the test is evaluated. In between the time the test is evaluated and the time your breakpoint is hit and you inspect the value, data has come into the buffer. That's why it also has data when you do Thread.Sleep.

Comment: Hi Shane, I saw the response you added to my other question, and I can see from reading other things that you wrote that you obviously know what you're talking about. As such, I don't mean to sound like I'm ignoring your advice - that is definitely not my intention!

The issue I'm having is that I have been trying to use the DataReceived handler in place of reading the bytes directly, but it's been returning inconsistent results. A lot of the time, I'd see 0x3F where I'd expect to see different values. With the ReadByte method, I'm seeing the correct values - at least when it behaves.